# C program does not run on buildroot

Tags: gtk3, buildroot

I work for buildroot. My purpose work GUI on my buildroot with `Gtk3.0` and `Gstreamer1.0`. I use Olinuxino A13 so I wrote GUI code(Gtk3.0 hello world example) on this with codeblocks. I use Debian wheezy. I want transfer this code from Debian wheezy to buildroot.

**I tried this**:

1. I transferred `/path_to_proectfile/bin/Debug/my_program.my_program` created by codeblocks. I wrote `./my_program` on terminal and code work. I transferred this file to my buildroot but `./my_program` does not work. It returns `No such file or directory` error.
2. I thought the problem might be compiling and tried compiled on terminal. I use `gcc -o my_program main.c 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0'` again work on Debian wheezy terminal. After I transferred to buildroot but result does not change. I tried different compile kind like `cc`,`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` etc. but every time `No such file or directory` error.

Finally when I don't use gtk library(Just use `printf Hello World`), I saw Hello world. When I add gtk library returns `No such file or directory` error. Have you any suggestion?

Comment: output of ```file my_program``` and ```ldd my_program```

Comment: @arved `file` output is: `command not found`                                             `ldd` output is: `checking sub-depends for 'not found' libc.so.6 => not found (0x00000000) /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3(0x00000000)`

Comment: I used `-static` command with `gcc` and Hello World example is works right now. I'm trying to run the GUI. I could not add `-static` command to compiler for GUI. Too many errors are returned and the execute file did not occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cross compile your program with the corresponding buildroot toolchain. It looks like you have transferred a binary which was built against a different libc (this gives a "No such file or directory" error).

The buildroot cross compiler with the correct libc can be used by setting CC to `"path_to_buildroot_output/host/bin/arm-linux-*-gcc"` (the exact name depends on which toolchain options you have chosen).

Comment: The buildroot cross compiler with the correct libc can be used by setting CC to "path_to_buildroot_output/host/bin/arm-linux-*-gcc" (the exact name depends on which toolchain options you have chosen).

Comment: @ Arnout. I examine `ldd` result on buildroot. It can not find many depends (e.g. `libgtk-3.so`). I researched this `libgtk-3.so` library in olinuxino board and I found it at `usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` folder. I added `-L/usr/bin/arm-linux-gneabihf` to gcc but result not change. I thinks the problem will solve if I add depends but I could not it. I am not sure really is there any need to use `path_to_buildroot_output / host / bin / arm-linux - * - gcc`.